# Vim background changes when using tmux

Tags: vim, tmux, neovim

I installed dracula colorscheme in neovim and configured tmux to use 24-bit color.
Outside of tmux everything works well, but when i enter vim inside of tmux, background changes.
Note: nothing changes except background.
Same issue appears in all colorschemes i tried.

In my init.vim file i have:
**set termguicolors**
[without tmux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpj5q.png) 
[with tmux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybIbY.png)

Comment: In your ~/.tmux.conf put `set -g default-terminal "screen-256color"`

Comment: Tmux doesnt support truecolor, afaik, so that could be your issue. You might need to set dracula’s colorterm config based on whether or not youre in tmux.

Comment: Can you show us your tmux configuration and vimrc, please, and tell us what the terminal type outside of tmux is (e.g., `xterm-256color`)?